# .csv result keep adding data from loop before

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, csv

My goal is to make csv from each loop, but the result keep adding data from loop before. I'm new in python

```
from collections import namedtuple
from datetime import date, timedelta
from os import close, name, pwrite, read, sep
from bs4.builder import HTML
from numpy import delete, select, split
from numpy.lib.function_base import append
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
from pandas.core.indexes.base import Index
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC, wait
import time
#import re
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys
import csv 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/Users/chromedriver')
    driver.get ("https://235/......")

    time.sleep(5)
   

    e = driver.find_element (By.NAME, "uid")
    e.send_keys ("aaaaa")
    e = driver.find_element (By.NAME, "pwd")
    e.send_keys ("bbbbb")
    
 
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"]').click()
  
   
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    code = driver.find_element (By.NAME, "onSubmit_noshowft").click()
    


    driver.get ("https://235/......")
    
    code = driver.find_element (By.CLASS_NAME, "navimage").click()
    
     
    a = ActionChains(driver)
  
    m = driver.find_element (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.wrapper:nth-child(2) div.full:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1) div.menutab ul.dropdown_menu > li.left:nth-child(8)")
   
    a.move_to_element(m).perform()
    
    z = driver.find_element (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.wrapper:nth-child(2) div.full:nth-child(1) div.menutab ul.dropdown_menu li.left:nth-child(8) ul:nth-child(1) > li:nth-child(3)")
    
    a.move_to_element(z).click().perform()

    driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)

    name=[]
    
    df = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/Documents/tes.csv')
    df = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/Documents/date.csv')
    for row in df.itertuples(index=True):
        
        column = row.stick

        l= driver.find_element (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#pop_mm_stock")
        l.clear()
        l.send_keys(column)  
       
        column1 = row.date
            
        cal1= driver.find_element (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#pop_bas_from")
        cal1.clear()
        cal1.send_keys(column1)
        print(column)
        n={'n': column}          
          
        name.append(n)       

        cal2= driver.find_element (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#pop_bas_to")
        cal2.clear()
        cal2.send_keys(column1)
        print(column1)
        n={'n': column1}
            
        name.append(n)

        show1=driver.find_element (By.CLASS_NAME, "button")
        a.move_to_element(show1).click().perform()
                                    
        time.sleep(5)
                                   
        head_up=WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[8]/div[1]/table[2]")))
            
        print(head_up.text)
        n={'n': head_up.text}
            
        name.append(n)

        pop_up=WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[8]/div[1]/div[1]/table[1]")))
           
        time.sleep(3)
        print(pop_up.text)
        n={'n': pop_up.text}
            
        name.append(n)
            
              
        d=pd.DataFrame(name)
                     
              
        d.to_csv(r'' + str(column) + str(column1) +  '_AVR.csv', index=False, header=False)
            
  
        
            
        driver.back()
                   

finally:

            print("finish")
```

The result is like this, where the first file correct, but the second file carries the first loop data.

```
file_1.csv
,n
0,KKWI
1,BL JL HJ BR   # SL SL SN SR
2,"DD 3,857 3.6B 9,244 1 YR 4,114 3.8B 9,228
YR 3,499 3.2B 9,209 2 DD 3,132 2.9B 9,230
PP 2,904 2.7B 9,210 3 YJ 2,292 2.1B 9,257
YJ 2,087 1.9B 9,201 4 PP 1,593 1.5B 9,181
```

file_2.csv

```
0,KKWI
1,BL JL HJ BR   # SL SL SN SR
2,"DD 3,857 3.6B 9,244 1 YR 4,114 3.8B 9,228
YR 3,499 3.2B 9,209 2 DD 3,132 2.9B 9,230
PP 2,904 2.7B 9,210 3 YJ 2,292 2.1B 9,257
YJ 2,087 1.9B 9,201 4 PP 1,593 1.5B 9,181
3,WWDD
4,BL JL HJ BR   # SL SL SN SR
5,"YY 3,610 3.3B 9,180 1 BB 2,445 2.2B 9,166
CC 1,517 1.4B 9,172 2 DD 2,013 1.8B 9,176
DD 1,448 1.3B 9,152 3 WW 1,443 1.3B 9,187
QQ 1,040 954.5M 9,177 4 CC 1,275 1.2B 9,176
FF 809 743.6M 9,192 5 AA 1,058 970.4M 9,171
JJ 764 700.6M 9,169 6 KJ 893 820.7M 9,190
```

What i tried to get is like this one, the file only contain from each loop :

file_1.csv

```
0,KKWI
1,BL JL HJ BR   # SL SL SN SR
2,"DD 3,857 3.6B 9,244 1 YR 4,114 3.8B 9,228
YR 3,499 3.2B 9,209 2 DD 3,132 2.9B 9,230
PP 2,904 2.7B 9,210 3 YJ 2,292 2.1B 9,257
YJ 2,087 1.9B 9,201 4 PP 1,593 1.5B 9,181
```

file_2.csv

```
3,WWDD
4,BL JL HJ BR   # SL SL SN SR
5,"YY 3,610 3.3B 9,180 1 BB 2,445 2.2B 9,166
CC 1,517 1.4B 9,172 2 DD 2,013 1.8B 9,176
DD 1,448 1.3B 9,152 3 WW 1,443 1.3B 9,187
QQ 1,040 954.5M 9,177 4 CC 1,275 1.2B 9,176
FF 809 743.6M 9,192 5 AA 1,058 970.4M 9,171
JJ 764 700.6M 9,169 6 KJ 893 820.7M 9,190
```

If anyone can help figure this out, I would appreciate it!

Comment: name=[] is outside the for loop. maybe this needs to be inside as the first line so it gets reset each loop. for now, you just keep appending it with each iteration.

Comment: i tried to move inside for name=[], still doesn't work

Comment: unclear why it doesn't work then. try  d=pd.DataFrame() after d.to_csv() in your loop. if this doesn't work, then name isn't being reset correctly as that's what's driving the d.to_csv(), as far as I can tell.

Comment: i have to wait, destination have bad ping result, i will try for your second idea, soon as connection is good enough, thank you..i wil tell the result

Comment: it doesn't work too, because d declared as dataframe that willl write it to d.to_csv()...